# Error in Google App Script custom function

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with three columns. All the numbers are in the Fahrenheit column, and the other two are filled from the functions.

```
Fahrenheit  Celsius ComputedFahrenheit
-200
-180
-160
-140
-120
-100
-80
-60
-40
-20
0
32
40
60
80
100
120
140
160
180
200
```

Celsius and ComputedFahrenheit columns are populated using these functions:

```
function f2c(fahrenheit) {
  if (typeof(fahrenheit) !== "number") {
    Logger.log(typeof(fahrenheit));
    throw "Fahrenheit column must contain numbers";
  }

  var celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5/9);
  return celsius;
}

function c2f (celsius) {
  if (typeof (celsius) !== "number") {
      throw "celsius must be a number";
  }

  var fahrenheit = (celsius*(9/5)) + 32;
  return fahrenheit;
}
```

All cells display data correct, except Row 14:

```
40     4.444444444      Error: Loading Data ..
```

Note: f2c uses the Farenheit column, c2f uses the Celsius column.

I cannot see the problem!

Project Key: MESQb2p_hPY7vMP_LZjizjHo2ajWN_uqm

SDC Key: df47e1281fe5caea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, **so this seems to be a bug in the new Google Sheets** related to custom functions that have [infinitely repeating decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) in their arguments, likely related to [this similar bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3800).

I created a [spreadsheet using your functions and data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBHH-sPx7UlYFyKE_GbGvAeZaUrLsqYjve2PO-2K9MQ/edit#gid=0). I found that the value would calculate *sometimes* after I refreshed, and other times stay stuck loading. However, if you round the output from `c2f()` and `f2c()`, the code is able to return *all* the time.

**This code works** and will end up with the *same precision* as if you don't round the output:

```
ROUND = Math.pow(10, 12);

function f2c(fahrenheit) {
  if (typeof(fahrenheit) !== "number") {
    Logger.log(typeof(fahrenheit));
    throw "Fahrenheit column must contain numbers";
  }

  var celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5/9);
  return Math.round(celsius * ROUND) / ROUND;
}

function c2f (celsius) {
  if (typeof (celsius) !== "number") {
      throw "celsius must be a number";
  }

  var fahrenheit = (celsius*(9/5)) + 32;
  return Math.round(fahrenheit * ROUND) / ROUND;
}
```

I've implemented it in [the sheet that I created](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBHH-sPx7UlYFyKE_GbGvAeZaUrLsqYjve2PO-2K9MQ/edit#gid=0). Let me know if that works!

Comment: When I reload, it shows 40, then goes back to the Error display.

Answer (score 0):

I've just recreated your spreadsheet and functions and on row 14 I get:

40  4.44444444444444    40

I suggest you try:

1. Creating a new spreadsheet
2. Creating a new google script file
3. Re-test

Comment: I created a new spreadsheet, new script file and it displays correctly. See my response below to br1ckb0t